# Does the different types of armor make the character look different?

Tags: divine-divinity

Does the armor change appearance on the character?  Meaning when you change out armor as you go through the game, does the character start showing different armor appearance, as you change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. For example, as a mage you will start out with purple robes:

[image: Starting armor for mage character]

Throughout the game you will find various armor sets, most of which have some sort of strength requirement in order to equip them. But equipping them does change the appearance of your avatar:

[image: Same character equipped with different armor]